# Why does "font" ignore "line-height" in CSS while "font-size" doesn't?

Tags: css

I experienced a very weird behavior. Why does test2 ignore line-height while test1 works fine? (the background-color is just to identify the containers better)

```
body {
    line-height:0.8;
}

.test1 {
    background:#fdf;
    font-size:24px;
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
}
.test2 {
    background:#ffd;
    font:24px Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tHUeg/4/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`font` is a shorthand property, and using it nukes any specific properties that make it up. Since `line-height` is included in `font` (usually seen as `24px/0.8 Arial,sans-serif`), it is reset to its default value.

Answer (score 2):

`font` includes `line-height` so it is overridden to the default.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font